# Apply every function to forEach javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, express, foreach

Thats my object tabs:

```
tabs: [
    {
      visible: true,
      title: 'tab 0',
      products: [{id:1, send: true, delivered: true}, {id:1, send: true, delivered: true}],
    },
    {
      visible: true,
      title: 'tab 1',
      products: [{id:11, send: true, delivered: false}, {id:21, send: true, delivered: true}],
    }
  ],
```

```
const allDerivered = (product) => product.delivered;
```

```
options.tabs.forEach(function (projectProducts){
   if (projectProducts.products.every(allDerivered)){
       statusTabs = 'DELIVERED';
  }
 });
```

Like the first products tabs are allDerivered it doesn't iterate through all the tabs object. How I can apply the allDerivered function to all the tabs?

Comment: Why do you have `async`? There is nothing asynchronous happening in the code you've shown.

Comment: Because i have only copy a part of the code, it does other things. How I can apply the every function forEach?

Comment: You **are** calling `allDelivered` for all tabs. More specifically, you're calling it for all tabs and at least one product in each tab. If it returns `false` for a product, you won't call the function for later products in that tab because you've used `every`, which stops when the callback returns a falsy value.  But I should note that it doesn't seem to make any sense to call it for every tab once you've set `statusTabs = 'DELIVERED'` once, since the code doesn't do anything at that point.

Comment: You *are* applying the function all of them. However, I'm not clear what you expect to happen. The computer will do exactly what you told it to do, however, it seems that's not what you *want* it to do. Right now, it's just assigning the value "DELIVERED" to some (hopefully) variable called `statusTabs`. Please describe what should be happening instead so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that you want to set `statusTabs` to `"DELIVERED"` if **all** products in **all** tabs are delivered, and not if **any** product in **any** tab is not delivered. If so, you can do that in a few ways.

You could use nested `every` calls:

```
if (options.tabs.every(({products}) => products.every(({delivered}) => delivered)) {
    statusTabs = "DELIVERED";
}
```

Or nested loops with a label and a directed `break`:

```
let allDelivered = true;
outer: for (const {products} of options.tabs) {
    for (const {delivered} of products) {
        if (!delivered) {
            allDelivered = false;
            break outer;
        }
    }
}
if (allDelivered) {
    statusTabs = "DELIVERED";
}
```

That's less cumbersome if you're also assigning to `statusTabs` in the false case:

```
statusTabs = "DELIVERED";
outer: for (const {products} of options.tabs) {
    for (const {delivered} of products) {
        if (!delivered) {
            statusTabs = "UNDELIVERED";
            break outer;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm going to make that assumption for the rest of the answer.

I didn't use `allDelivered` in the above because the name doesn't match what the function does (it only checks if **one** product is delivered, not if the all are) and because what the function does is just a single check of a property value which is just as clear done inline. But if you wanted a reusable function that does that check, you could have one:

```
const isDelivered = ({delivered}) => delivered;
```

Then the two code blocks above would be:

```
if (options.tabs.every(({products}) => products.every(isDelivered)) {
    statusTabs = "DELIVERED";
}
```

Or nested loops with a label and a directed `break`:

```
statusTabs = "DELIVERED";
outer: for (const {products} of options.tabs) {
    for (const product of products) {
        if (isDelivered(product)) {
            statusTabs = "UNDELIVERED";
            break outer;
        }
    }
}
```

You could go further and have an `allProductsDelivered` function for tabs:

```
const allProductsDelivered = ({products}) => products.every(isDelivered);
```

Then the nested `every` would be:

```
if (options.tabs.every(allProductsDelivered)) {
    statusTabs = "DELIVERED";
}
```

And the loops version would be:

```
statusTabs = "DELIVERED";
for (const {products} of options.tabs) {
    if (!allProductsDelivered(tab)) {
        statusTabs = "UNDELIVERED";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the nested loops with `break outer`, especially if the OP does do any async stuff.

Comment: @Keith - Good point, the OP did mention there was some `async` stuff as well...

Comment: @Keith - Mind you, the nested loops version was wrong initially. :-D I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want something like this:

```js
const tabs = [{
    visible: true,
    title: 'tab 0',
    products: [{
      id: 1,
      send: true,
      delivered: true
    }, {
      id: 1,
      send: true,
      delivered: true
    }],
  },
  {
    visible: true,
    title: 'tab 1',
    products: [{
      id: 11,
      send: true,
      delivered: false
    }, {
      id: 21,
      send: true,
      delivered: true
    }],
  }
];

const isNotDelivered = (product) => product.delivered == false;

tabs.forEach(tab => {
  const areAllProductsDelivered = !tab.products.find(isNotDelivered);
  if (areAllProductsDelivered) {
    console.log(`${tab.title} is completely delivered`);
  } else {
    console.log(`${tab.title} is NOT completely delivered`);
  }
});
```